# How to update sessionStorage - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, session-storage

I am building an Angular app that requires login to jump into it. While login, I am adding data to `sessionStorage` which I am getting with the *login API*.

The structure of the data being stored in `sessionStorage` is something like this:

```
obj {
 key1: value1,
 key2: value2,
 ............,
 ............,
 anotherObj: {
  anotherKey1: anotherValue1,
  anotherKey2: anotherValue2,
 }
}
```

Here is the code to login and setting data to `sessionStorage`:

```
if(username && password) {
  this._http.post('/api/suser/login', formData).subscribe(res => {
    if (res['status'] === 'success') {
      sessionStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(res['result']));
    }
  });
}
```

Now, I have one angular component which is used to update that data. It's getting update at the backend but how can I update `sessionStorage` simultaneously so that my view can also changed accordingly. I need to logout and then login back to reflect changes in the `sessionStorage`.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You want to update 'data' in sessionStorage based on operation in another angular component for which data is getting updated in backend?

Comment: @ZamAbdulVahid Yes exactly.

Comment: Ive added my answer. Please have a look

Answer (score 1):

```
let mySessionData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('data'));
```

This would get you the session value as an object and you can modify as per your requirement. Once your changes are updated to the object, save it back to session storage.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(mySessionData));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. But I want to know one more thing that how to refresh component after updating sessionStorage. I want to refresh my component so that changes can reflect into view(browser) also. I don't want to use `window.location.reload()`

Comment: You need to create a 'BehaviorSubject' and subscribe to the value change.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request correctly, you need other components to be able to track changes in the SessionStorage and display the changes that you make in it.
Then you better use a service that will save data in SessionStorage and inform all components who are subscribed to the event of changing this data.

To do this, you need to use Observable from RxJS there is an article with an example https://medium.com/@weswhite/angular-behaviorsubject-service-60485ef064fc